# Sitecore Personalization on EXM is not working

Tags: exm, personalization

We use `Sitecore 9 update 1` and we utilize the out of the box `Email Experience Manager (EXM)` of it. But we encountered an issue with regards to personalization of an email campaign. It seems the personalization using rules/condition is not working.

Anybody from this community experienced and solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We are also experiencing this on our Sitecore 9 Update 1 Environment. Personalization in the EXM is not working.

Comment: You should create ticket to Sitecore Support

Comment: There is already Cumulative hotfix for EXM 9.0 Update-1  -> https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/467253 <- but it is not solving this particular issue as far as I can see in release notes

Comment: All rules don't work? Or some particular?

Comment: Hi Anton, we've tried most of the available conditions in there and any of them don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed in the [cumulative hotfix for EXM 9.0 Update-1](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/467253)

The problem is that the contact is never being identified during dispatch. This needs to happen in the ensureSessionContext pipeline.

Add the following pipeline processor

```
public class LoadEmailRenderSessionContact
{
    public ContactRepositoryBase ContactRepository { get; set; }

    public void Process(InitializeTrackerArgs args)
    {
        if (!ExmContext.IsRenderRequest || ExmContext.ContactIdentifier == null || ContactRepository == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Contact contact = ContactRepository.LoadContact(ExmContext.ContactIdentifier.Source, ExmContext.ContactIdentifier.Identifier);

        if (contact == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        args.Session.Contact = contact;
    }
}
```

and add it to the ensureSessionContext pipeline:

```
<ensureSessionContext role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or DedicatedDispatch or ContentDelivery">
    <processor type="FooBar.LoadEmailRenderSessionContact, FooBar" x:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.LoadContact, Sitecore.Analytics']" resolve="true">
        <ContactRepository ref="contactRepository" />
    </processor>
</ensureSessionContext>
```

Additionally, you should make sure that the tracker is enabled for the site as MVC personalization will otherwise not work i.e. set enableTracking="true" on the exm site e.g..

```
<site name="exm" enableTracking="true" inherits="shell" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" startItem="/none" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" />
```